# Function to concat two char* in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, strcat

First off, I'm a C# programmer, so my working knowledge of C++ is fairly limited. I took it back in college, but haven't touched it in 10 years, so please forgive me if this is relatively simple stuff.

I'm attempting to make a DLL that I can use in C# that implements the libwpd library.

I've managed to create a DLL that exports 2 functions that I can access via  P/Invoke.  The first returns a constant integer (generated by visual studio as a sample), the 2nd a string.

If I return a constant string from the function, it passes successfully to C# and I can read it on the other end, so I know the data is being passed back.

The problem I'm running into is with libwpd.  I've had to modify their TextDocumentGenerator.cpp file to add the information to a char* instead of using the printf that they use so I can access it later.

I've added a variable definition to the public section of the header file so I can read it from the calling code.

Now, I'm trying to write a function that allows me to add the char* given by libwpd to the external char*.

I've come up with this:

```
char* addString(const char* addThis, char* toThis)
{
char* copier  = (char*)malloc(strlen(toThis) + 1 + 1);
strcpy(copier, toThis);
strcpy(copier, "1");

toThis = (char*)malloc(strlen(copier) + 1);
strcpy(toThis, copier);

return copier;
}
```

But when I pass the information back, I get a blank string.

I call the function by calling `totalFile = addString("\n", totalFile);`

(I realize it should only technically add "1" to the string repeatedly, but it's not doing even that)

If i change the strcpy to strcat for the copier lines, it locks up.

I don't know how to create a program in C++ so I can even step through the functions to see what's happening.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `strcpy(copier, toThis); strcpy(copier, "1");` - for one thing, the second `strcpy` overwrites the results of the first.

Comment: If you find yourself using `malloc` in C++, it almost always means you're doing something wrong.  If you find yourself using `new` in C++, it may still mean you're doing something wrong; many of the common scenarios where `new` would be needed are already provided in the standard template library.

Comment: @Trevor A friendly tip: I would suggest compiling your C++ project as C++/CLI, and in the project create a managed wrapper for the native code. That way, it is MUCH cleaner interfacing with it. You just add a reference as usual and you can create managed instances of your wrapper, which contains unmanaged pointers to the native classes.

Comment: Don't forget to write and export another function in your DLL to free the allocated string. DLL has it's own memory manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you aware of existence of `std::string`? It's a class that handles strings in C++; `char *` is legacy from C.

`std::string` provides `+` operator, that does what you want.

Comment: I wasn't aware of std::string.  The existing code I have to work with and my school used char*, so that's what I was trying to use.  I don't seem to have access to std::string (missing an include?) but will look for it.

Comment: He wants to call this from c#, so `std::string` is not going to work (at least for the parameters and return value).

Comment: #include <string>. Next time, google for "cppreference <whatever>" to get such information ;)

Comment: @crashmstr, do you know that there are two ways of getting `char *` from string? `c_str()` and `&str[0]`?

Comment: Blah.  Apparently using #include <string> conflicts with the existing required stream class from libwpd.  C makes my eyes bleed.  thanks for all your assistance.  Not sure where I'm going from here.

Comment: After fiddling with it for a bit, std::string was the way to go and scrapping this monstrosity of a function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate enough space for the return string, copy the inital string into the destination buffer, and then call strcat to append the extra info.

For example:

```
char* addString(const char* addThis, const char* toThis)
{
    char* destination = (char*)malloc( strlen( addThis ) + strlen( toThis ) + 1 );
    strcpy( destination, toThis );
    strcat( destination, addThis );
    return destination;
}
```

Don't forget you'll need to call `free( destination )` at some point after calling this function.

EDIT: 
Of course, this is just me fixing the function proposed in your question.  Really, it's not a great idea to return a pointer from a function and count on the caller to free it.  Since you're using C++ rather than C, you'd likely be much better off using some C++ constructs, such as std::string or at the very least, wrapping the char* in a shared_ptr or similar.

If you're going to be writing C++, I'd recommend buying yourself [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on the subject, it really is far too easy to shoot yourself in the foot if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: This is not necessarily a good idea.  You've put the responsibility of the caller to free the block of memory you allocated.  This is as bad as not using `shared_ptr`.  You're allocating memory, then saying "be damned with it".  Some may disagree, but I find this bad practice.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I agree, personally I'd never write a function like this.  I was just fixing the mess of a function proposed in the question.  Might edit in a disclaimer to that effect I suppose.

Comment: The strcmp for the first one was what causing it to lock up when i changed it.  Doing it as strcpy/strcmp let it run past this point.  I'll probably look into sprintf or std::string if i can get past the linking errors.  Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are replacing a `printf()` call, [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) would probably be the easiest way to create your string.

Comment: This looked relatively promising until the required includes broke libwpd.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Trevor: It *should* only need the same include that is also required for `printf`, the `<stdio.h>` header.

Answer (score 0):

First off, Griwes is correct.  You have no business doing what you are doing and marking this question as C++.  The simple reason being, this is not how we work with strings in C++.

As you are a C# programmer you are well aware of the `String` class.  Well, `std::string` is similar.  It takes the leg-work out of dealing with strings so that you do not have to go down the painful route that you're going down.

To concatenate two strings together in C++, it's as simple as:

```
std::string a = "I slept with ";
std::string b = "a heavy heart.";
std::string c = a + b;
```

Voila.

Comment: The downside to this is using legacy code or code written with char* originally.  Can you convert from a std::string to a char* and back again without issue?  I also don't have access to the std::string as it stands (missing an include somewhere).  In school and in the existing source code that I'm modifying, char* was used so I used char*.   I will definitely look into std::string though if I can get access to it.

Comment: @TrevorWatson, yes.  in the above example, calling `c.c_str()` will give you a regular `const char*`.

Comment: @TrevorWatson: `std::string` is part of the standard template library.  It will be included with any decent C++ compiler.  Using `char *` instead of `std::string` is analogous to using `char[]` in C# instead of using a `System.String`.